# How do I remove Mapbox sources from Mapbox studio?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I've got a message for limitation of max resources.

So, I want to remove some unused Mapbox sources from Style Studio.

How Can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those sources are from mapbox and they will not be included in your style if you are not using them. You can check which are the sources being used by pressing Settings in the top right corner and scroll down:

[image: Screenshot from mapbox settings]

Comment: I know that. but it just the number of counts, doesn't help. 
When I make a new style in mapbox studio, it doesn't included. 
I can import that mapbox resource but how to remove it?